Collect StackExchange.Redis metrics
I need to collect basic redis connection metrics, at least message duration. Is there any way to do it for StackExchange.Redis library and its ConnectionMultiplexer?
I've found OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.StackExchangeRedis library, but it doesn't provide any metrics, only tracing info. Also I've found pull request with initial native metrics. However it is quite old and still not merged. Maybe there are some 3rd-party solutions?
